# Defining Classes in JS (ES5 vs Prototype)

Tags: javascript, oop

I am looking at some common ways of defining classes ([Constructor Pattern in Book by Addy Osmani](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#constructorpatternjavascript)).

2 main ways I see:

- Simple Prototypes:

  ```
  function Person(name) { this.name = name; }
  Person.prototype.getName = function() { return this.name; }
  ```
- ES5 `Object.create`, `Object.defineProperties`

I am wondering, why might I even consider the ES5 way which appears to be alot more complicated? Is there any advantages? Maybe the only main advantage is having read-only properties like some strongly typed language?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Object.defineProperties` is only needed if you want those properties to have particular attributes, e.g. non-enumerable, read-only, or with getters or setter functions.

There's no need to use it for normal classes and their methods, where the "simple prototype" method you describe is perfectly adequate.